# Wordpress woocommerce auto reloading

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have a ecommerce site in wordpress woocommerce theme. Whether i put something in the cart or not.
The cart page is autoloading in every 5 seconds. i tried googling this issue but couldn't find any solution. Please help..

Comment: there might be some jQuery issue which conflict with woocommerce but you can try this code for quick fix add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_woocommerce_cart_fragments', 11); 
function dequeue_woocommerce_cart_fragments() { wp_dequeue_script('wc-cart-fragments'); }

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added any jquery code then check with that code and If you haven't added any code then try with deactivate all plugin excepting woocommere. May be some other plugins causing an issue.